# Upgrade magento 2.2.2 to 2.3.2 getting error

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.2

We are trying to upgrade a Magento 2.2.2 site to Magento 2.3.2, when executing `**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**` we get the error...

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\SimpleProductPrice::reindexAll() in /var/www/html/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Full.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price.php(66): Bss\MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer\Model\Indexer\Product\Price\Action\Full->execute()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(416): Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price->executeFull()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(248): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexAll()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand.php(87): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexAll()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Argv in /var/www/html/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Full.php on line 51
```

the error message 
[enter link description here](https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/13/d43a56cda5ad120ed77e9dbbdf1076df-full.png)

Comment: Seems issue with BSS-Multi store view pricing module. Disable it first then upgrade

Comment: after that enable again ?

Comment: You need to check with module vendor weather they have compatible version of that module or not? otherwise you need to add that patch.

Comment: - how to check that ?
- if not want i can do ?
- which patch ?

Answer (score 0):

issue is not related to the magento

the third party extension is not compatible with magneto2.3.2

first disable the extension BSS_MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer and clear cache and run the indexer command again

Comment: after that enable again ??????

Comment: no please install magento2.3.2 compaitible extension, or contact extension provide to provide you updated package

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: please get the updated package from bss company, that is compaitible with magento 2.3.2

Comment: please provide me with link or command please

Answer (score 0):

from what I experienced while, I was upgrading Magneto, It could be one of theses things:
    app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Full::execute()

- may use a removed method.
- may a method that its encapsulation (from protected to private)  was changed .
- may use a removed property.
- may use a property with changed encapsulation (from protected to private).
- may use a method that has it extensions changed.

The easiest fix is to check if the third party extension has new version compatible with Magento 2.3.2, if that the case swap it with older one.